# Create New Pipeline on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, strong-parameters, amazon-data-pipeline

I created and configured Data Pipeline to run AWS CLI commands that stop and start Amazon EC2 instances at scheduled intervals, but after I activated it, then data pipeline status is going failed like this picture below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq2za.png)

I confuse about its parameter that If filled is like this:

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-0bbd2c85 --region ap-southeast-1a;
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-1721b699 --region ap-southeast-1a;
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-1321b69d --region ap-southeast-1a;
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-1121b69f --region ap-southeast-1a;
aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-0bbd2c85 --region ap-southeast-1a;
aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-1721b699 --region ap-southeast-1a;
aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-1321b69d --region ap-southeast-1a;
aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-1121b69f --region ap-southeast-1a;
```

Before I activate it, there are also warning like those below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPFVq.png)

Comment: Based on press release references, I wonder you are just supposed to use ap-southeast-1  instead of ap-southeast-1a  https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/02/20/aws-data-pipeline-now-available-in-four-new-regions/

Answer (score 0):

Data Pipeline can actually provision EC2 instances for you.

Take a look at this documentation for configuring EC2 instances using Data Pipeline: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-ec2resource.html

Also, have a look at this simple pipeline sample.  This should help you get started: https://github.com/awslabs/data-pipeline-samples/tree/master/samples/helloworld

This sample shows you how to run a simple shell script on EC2.